The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES Error in kotlin?
I have an SDK project and I want to test whether Proguard corrupts some files when isMinifyEnabled true if so I try to configure proguard for release version, but I encounter the following error. I am trying to run this SDK project in build Variant release, but I get an error like this:

Error running 'app' The application could not be installed:
INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES


Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed:
INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

When I select debug mode in Build Variant, the app works fine.
I didn't understand where the problem came from. I created generate signed bundle apk and I kept getting the same error. I tried some things from this link but I couldn't do it :
What is INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error?
I don't know why I'm getting this error. This is the first time I've encountered this error and I couldn't find a solution. Please help. I have shared the codes that I think may be necessary. If there is an extra code that is required, I can share it.
here are my configurations
build.gradle.kts (Module :app)
android {
    namespace = "xxx"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "xxx"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

     
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    } ... 
    dependencies {
        ...
       // implementation(project(":sdk")). // I commented this out to test the sdk library
        implementation("com.xxx:1.0.0")
    }

settings.gradle
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
      //  mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url =
                uri("xxx")

            credentials {
                username = "xxx"
                password = "xxx"
            }
        }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "xxx"
rootProject.buildFileName = "build.gradle.kts"
//include(":app", ":sdk")
include(":app")


For testing of ProGuard, you can specify to use the default debug sign key for the release build variant. This way, you can prevent certificate errors on local testing. Modify your module's build.gradle like this:
android {
    //...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug  // sign release build with debug key
        }
    }
}

Don't forget to remove the signingConfig line when building a signed APK for publishing in Play Store!
Please report back if that works in your case.
